# Security measures for Ubuntu 10.4

Tags: ubuntu, security, ubuntu-10.04

I'm currently using a hosted VPS on linode, I was wondering if a daily `apt-get update` and `apt-get upgrade` is providing a 'secure' enough measurement.

Comment: Hardening of the OS itself is required. Firewall/IP tables configuration is needed, I think.

Answer (score 1):

Daily updates will make sure that your software is updated and potentially close vulnerabilities there, but as JFW commented, you should take time and update the firewall/IPTables to close off any unnecessary ports and you should also disable any services you're not using.

Comment: What's a standard iptables config for a server that runs Apache, Postfix (25,110,143), SSH and FTP? should I just block EVERYTHING else? Thanks